# Всплывающая подсказка в Яндекс.Картах

Tags: javascript, html, yandex-maps-api

Использую [**Яндекс.Карты API 1.1**](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/1.x/mod/concepts/regions-docpage/).

Сделал вывод нескольких регионов как единое целое и их закрашивание в один цвет. Такой вопрос - есть ли возможность сделать всплывающую подсказку как на [**данном примере**](https://yandex.github.io/mapsapi-examples-old/html/regions-filterregions.html), но только со своим текстом (типа `"Название_области ололо"`?

Пока я сделал вывод желаемого мне текста на совокупности регионов с помощью `new Placemark` [(**ссылка на fiddle**)](https://jsfiddle.net/9yen429p/), но хотелось бы, чтобы данный текст отображался сразу при наведении на совокупность регионов без всяких `Placemark`.

Возможно ли это?

```
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/1.1/index.xml?modules=regions" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">
    <!-- ДЛЯ ВЫВОДА ИНДЕКСА МАССИВА (ДЛЯ ПОДДЕРЖКИ В IE) -->
        (function(A) {
            A.indexOf = A.indexOf || function(object) {
                for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) {
                    if (i in this && this[i] === object) {
                        return i; } }
                return -1;
            };
        })(Array.prototype);

        <!-- СОЗДАНИЕ КАРТЫ -->
        YMaps.jQuery(function () {
            var map = new YMaps.Map(YMaps.jQuery("#YMapsID")[0]);
            map.setCenter(new YMaps.GeoPoint(55, 55), 4);
            var zoom = new YMaps.Zoom();map.addControl(zoom);map.enableScrollZoom(true);
            YMaps.Regions.load("ru", function (state, response) {
                if (state == YMaps.State.SUCCESS) {

                  <!-- 1-Я СОВОКУПНОСТЬ РЕГИОНОВ -->
                  var shapes, polygon;
                  var regionVba1 = response.filter(function (obj) {
                  var names = [
"Кировская область", "Нижегородская область", "Пензенская область", "Республика Марий Эл", "Республика Мордовия", "Самарская область", "Саратовская область", "Ульяновская область", "Чувашская Республика"
                  ];
                  return (names.indexOf(obj.name) > -1);
              });
              for (var i = 0; i < regionVba1.length; i++) {
                  shapes = regionVba1[i].metaDataProperty.encodedShapes;
                  for (var ix = shapes.length; ix--; ) {
                      polygon = YMaps.Polygon.fromEncodedPoints(
                          shapes[ix].coords,
                          shapes[ix].levels
                      );
                      polygon.setStyle({
                          polygonStyle: {
                              fillColor: "b00c0c50",
                              strokeColor: "b00c0c"
                          }
                      }); 
                      map.addOverlay(polygon);
                  }
              }

              <!-- Выводим нужный нам текст -->
              var placemark1 = new YMaps.Placemark(new YMaps.GeoPoint(45, 54), {hasHint: true});
              placemark1.name = "Поволжская зона";
              map.addOverlay(placemark1);

                } else {
                    alert ("Error: " + response.Error.Message)
                } });
        })
    </script>
```

Насколько я понимаю, необходимо поставить [**такой хинт**](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/1.x/dg/tasks/how-to-add-hint-docpage/), но не понимаю, как привязать его к совокупности регионов `regionVba1`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте:

```
polygon.setOptions({
    hasHint: true
});
polygon.name = regionVba1[i].name;
```

[Работающий пример](https://jsfiddle.net/3kygf07x/1/)

Comment: То, что доктор прописал, спасибо) P.S. награду только через 22 часа смогу отдать

Comment: Ок, всегда пожалуйста